# Latex3 floating point calculations in longtblr (tabularray)

Tags: tables, floats, latex3, calculations, tabularray

I'm learning LaTeX3 and trying to do simple calculations on floats in a longtblr environment.

Trouble is that I cannot manage to dynamically compute sub-totals per row. The global total is working fine but the sub-total is evaluated only once. (l_subtot_fp should be 6 on the first row and 8 on the second)

The second problem is : How do you append rows containing the alignment character "&" ? I get "Misplaced alignment tab character &." error if I add them.

I suspect a TeX expansion enigma, can anyone clarify this ?

Thanks a lot in advance for any helping answer !

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_rowlist_tl
\fp_set:Nn \g_total_fp {0}

\newcommand*{\NewRow}[3]{
    \fp_set:Nn \l_subtot_fp {#2}
    \fp_set:Nn \l_subtot_fp { \l_subtot_fp * #3 }
    % Next line should contain three "&" like this:
    % \tl_put_right:Nn \g_rowlist_tl {#1 & #2 & #3 & {\fp_use:N \l_subtot_fp}\\}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \g_rowlist_tl {#1 #2 #3 {\fp_use:N \l_subtot_fp}\\}
    \fp_add:Nn \g_total_fp {\l_subtot_fp}
}

\begin{document}

\NewRow{A}{3}{2}
\NewRow{B}{2}{4}

% Dynamic version (NOT WORKING)
\begin{longtblr}{cccc}
    \tl_use:N \g_rowlist_tl
    Total &&& \fp_eval:n {\g_total_fp}
\end{longtblr}

% What I would like to generate
\begin{longtblr}{cccc}
    A & 3 & 2 & 6\\
    B & 2 & 4 & 8\\
    Total &&& 14
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: You may wait for version 2022B of `tabularray` which will be released on June 1st. See https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/81 for more details.

Comment: @L.J.R. Thanks for making me discover this future functionality. I also discovered the functional package (https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) which seems interesting.

Comment: It's my pleasure, since I am the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I think it would be better to use `functional` library to do programming inside `tabularray` tables, you could still use `expl3` if  you want. You may compare this answer with [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645074/generate-tabularray-and-compute-sub-result-for-each-row-using-functional-library/645116#645116) for a similar question asked by the OP.

---

Here are some suggestions for the code in the question:

(1) `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` should only include `expl3` code only. Putting `\begin{document}` inside them may cause problems. Also any code after `\end{document}` is omitted, so it is no use writing `\ExplSyntaxOff` after it.

(2) `\fp_set:Nn` can do many kinds of calculation in its second argument. So

```
\fp_set:Nn \l_subtot_fp {#2}
\fp_set:Nn \l_subtot_fp { \l_subtot_fp * #3 }
```

can be simplified as

```
\fp_set:Nn \l_subtot_fp {#2 * #3}
```

(3) You need to expand the value of `\l_subtot_fp` before adding it into `\g_rowlist_tl`. This can be done with `e` variant of arguments.
And you can create `e` variant of commands with `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` function.

(4) You need to use outer specification `expand=\g_rowlist_tl` since you want to expand it inside the tabularray table.

The following is the modified code which produces the expected result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_rowlist_tl
\fp_set:Nn \g_total_fp {0}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_put_right:Nn {Ne}
\newcommand*\NewRow[3]{
  \fp_set:Nn \l_subtot_fp {#2 * #3}
  \tl_put_right:Nn \g_rowlist_tl {#1 & #2 & #3 &}
  \tl_put_right:Ne \g_rowlist_tl {\fp_use:N \l_subtot_fp}
  \tl_put_right:Nn \g_rowlist_tl {\\}
  \fp_add:Nn \g_total_fp {\l_subtot_fp}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\NewRow{A}{3}{2}
\NewRow{B}{2}{4}

% Dynamic version (NOW WORKING)
\ExplSyntaxOn
\begin{longtblr}[expand=\g_rowlist_tl]{cccc}
    \g_rowlist_tl
    Total &&& \fp_use:N \g_total_fp
\end{longtblr}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% What I would like to generate
\begin{longtblr}{cccc}
    A & 3 & 2 & 6\\
    B & 2 & 4 & 8\\
    Total &&& 14
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @L.J.R. ! Your suggestions are all pertinent and your explanation is very clear. The example you provided is indeed working as intended.