# Generate tabularray and compute sub-result for each row using functional library

Tags: tables, tabularray

I must use **longtblr** from **tabularray** package and would like to calculate simple products on each row.

Trouble is, the product displayed in the final result is the same for every row : the product from the ending row. As illustrated below, the first row should end with 4.4 and not 8.

[image: wrong output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\FpNew \Total
\PrgNewFunction \Product {mmm} {
  \FpSet \SubTotal {#2 * #3}
  \TlSet \Row {#1 & #2 & #3 & {\FpUse \SubTotal}\\}
  \FpAdd \Total {\FpUse \SubTotal}
  \Return {\TlUse \Row}
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[evaluate=\Product]{cccc}
  \Product{Text}{1.1}{4}
  \Product{Text}{4}{2}
  Total &&& \FpUse \Total
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

I'm using latest **tabularray** and **functional** packages from github for these functionalities.

I'm also computing the total sum from the last column and it is working fine.

Thanks in advance for any helpful answer !
And many thanks to @L.J.R. for creating this wonderful TeX package (the most feature-packed tabular environment to my knowledge) !

Comment: Looks like you can try printing out the value of `Row` before each return to see what will be executed.

Comment: Ah, the problem here is FpUse will not be "executed"... (see, I told the author that implicitly doing things without letting users understand how expansion works in TeX is not good idea...)

Comment: Try something like this, not tested `\PrgNewFunction \SetRow {mmmm} {\TlSet \Row {#1 & #2 & #3 & #4\\}}` + `\SetRow {#1} {#2} {#3} {\FpUse \SubTotal}`

Comment: @user202729 The main focus of `functional` package is to avoid using argument variants or `\exp_args`.  Users still need to know some about expansion, and there are several expansion functions provided in `functional` package.

Comment: Hm, I consider that a minor point it's it's not *that* inconvenient compared to the tmp-variable thing -- nevertheless what I'm saying here is that the package documentation is not clear on how it works internally in terms of TeX (which causes the confusion in at least this one example), and how it can be used in conjunction with other TeX interface (how to pass data from expl3-like interface to functional-like interface and vice versa, make wrapper of expl3-like libraries, etc.) --not to demand features (yes, software development is hard), just some suggestions.

Comment: @L.J.R. ↑ (also maybe make a mention that it prints out the result if (and only if) it's at top level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid potential naming conflicts with commands in LaTeX kernel and other packages, [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package has changed its naming scheme for functions from `\UpperCamelCase` to `\lowerCamelCase` since version 2022G (2022-05-22).

Also there is some renaming for single-word functions (see the [changelog](https://github.com/lvjr/functional/wiki/ChangeLog)). For example, `\Return` has been renamed as `\prgReturn`.

For backward compatibility, those old UpperCamelCase function names can still be used for some time as long as they are  not used by kernel or other packages, but they will be removed in the future.

---

An inner function is evaluated only when it occurs at the beginning of an argument. So the following line

```
\tlSet \Row {#1 & #2 & #3 & {\fpUse \SubTotal}\\}
```

need to be changed to

```
\tlSet \Row {#1 & #2 & #3 & }
\tlPutRight \Row {\fpUse \SubTotal}
\tlPutRight \Row {\\}
```

Now you get the expected result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\fpNew \Total
\prgNewFunction \Product {mmm} {
  \fpSet \SubTotal {#2 * #3}
  \tlSet \Row {#1 & #2 & #3 & }
  \tlPutRight \Row {\fpUse \SubTotal}
  \tlPutRight \Row {\\}
  \fpAdd \Total {\fpUse \SubTotal}
  \prgReturn {\tlUse \Row}
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[evaluate=\Product]{cccc}
  \Product{Text}{1.1}{4}
  \Product{Text}{4}{2}
  Total &&& \fpUse \Total
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (more remark) Also there's no need for TF variant of everything... just make the boolean-output function and pass it to BoolVarIfTF (maybe the other is slightly faster, but scanning every argument every time, make group, etc. likely is terribly slow *anyway*)

Comment: && there's no way I can set a TL to some token? `\TlSet \lx {\ExpNot{\IntEval{1+2}}}
` doesn't work in the current version

Comment: (off topic here but) While testing different things I notice that `\TlSet \lx {\UseOne{a}\UseOne{b}}
` will set it to b instead of ab (if it sets to ab then it could be used here, just wrap UseOne around things as well)

Comment: @user202729 Could you open a new question on this site? Or on https://github.com/lvjr/functional/discussions? It is always hard to discuss in comments.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and working example @L.J.R. Works like a charm for my usecase ! I guess the important part is about the need to use top-level argument to ensure evaluation. As you said "An inner function is evaluated only when it occurs at the beginning of an argument."

Comment: A variation on this problem using expl3 instead can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644932/latex3-floating-point-calculations-in-longtblr-tabularray