# Literature Review Summary Table automation using tabularray, biblatex and functional

Tags: biblatex, tabularray, functional

I want to automate the generation of the following table using `tabularray` and `functional`.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{key1,
    author = {John Doe and Miles Marsh},
    year = {2012},
    title = {A example of article in biblatex},
}
@article{key2,
    author = {Martha Ackley and Rodrigo Rojas and Rodolph Cardo},
    year = {2015},
    title = {Another example of article in biblatex},
}
@article{key3,
    author = {Alan Doe},
    year = {2019},
    title = {Yet another example of article in biblatex},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{functional}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand\ColNameauthor{Authors}
\newcommand\ColNameyear{Year}
\newcommand\ColNametitle{Title}
\newcommand\ColNameremark{Remarks}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\prgNewFunction \RepeatCell {mmm}  {
    \tlSet \lTmpaTl {\intReplicate {\intEval{#1}} {#2 &}}
    \tlPutRight \lTmpaTl {#3\\}
    \tlUse \lTmpaTl
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff

\begin{document}
\begin{talltblr}[
    caption={How the table should look},
    ]{
    colspec = {cX[1]X[1.5]X[2.5]},
    width = \linewidth,
    hline{1,Z} = {solid,0.6pt},
    hline{2} = {solid,0.4pt},
    cell{2-Z}{1} = {c,cmd=\citeyear},
    cell{2-Z}{2} = {c,cmd=\citeauthor},
    cell{2-Z}{3} = {l,cmd=\citetitle},
    row{1} = {cmd={},font=\bfseries,c},
    }
    Year & Authors & Title & Remarks \\
    key1 & key1 & key1 & \lipsum[2][1-2] \\ 
    key2 & key2 & key2 & \lipsum[2][1-2] \\ 
    key3 & key3 & key3 & \lipsum[2][1-2] \\ 
\end{talltblr}

\vspace{5ex}

\begin{talltblr}[
    evaluate = \RepeatCell,
    caption  = {Table using functional},
    ]{
    colspec  = {cX[1]X[1.5]X[2.5]},
    width    = \linewidth,
    hline{1,Z} = {solid,0.6pt},
    hline{2} = {solid,0.4pt},
    cell{2-Z}{1} = {c,cmd=\citeyear},
    cell{2-Z}{2} = {c,cmd=\citeauthor},
    cell{2-Z}{3} = {l,cmd=\citetitle},
    row{1} = {cmd={},font=\bfseries,c},
    }
    \ColNameyear & \ColNameauthor & \ColNametitle & \ColNameremark \\
    \RepeatCell{3}{key1}{\lipsum[2][1-2]}
    \RepeatCell{3}{key2}{\lipsum[2][1-2]}
    \RepeatCell{3}{key3}{\lipsum[2][1-2]}
\end{talltblr}
\end{document}
```

The output is this:

[image: table output]

My question is:

Is there a better way to store the field names? (the column names) and what should be my next step if I want to have a environment that works like this:

```
\begin{LitReviewTable}[year,author,title,remarks]
   \LiteratureItem{key1}{Remark contents}
   \LiteratureItem{key2}{Remark contents}
\end{LitReviewTable}
```

And the cells should be repeated automatically the same number of fields in the optional argument.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645074/generate-tabularray-and-compute-sub-result-for-each-row-using-functional-library?rq=1, especially the comments discussing expansion and the need to see the top level.

Comment: @cfr, I am sorry, maybe I'm a little dumb but I still don't see the problem. Currently the code works and is not repeating the result as in the question you linked. By top level do you mean that it is not possible to wrap or alias my tabular into another environment? A thousand apologies if I can't see the problem yet, I'm just learning to program using functional. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I don't see a point to use tabularray or functional here. tabularray is slow and it is not trivial to understand how it expands and parses its contents. It is quite powerful and for complicated table layouts that is nice, but you have a simple tabular that can be easily be set with longtable +  booktabs.

Comment: You would need `\LiteratureItem` to be a top-level command. You couldn't, say, define it in terms of `\RepeatCell` etc. At least, I don't think you could in any straightforward way. I don't know if it would work to wrap the environment in `LitReviewTable`. I've only very briefly experimented with the package. I just know it parses the environment contents to figure the structure out and so expansion becomes more complicated. But, as @UlrikeFischer says, you don't really seem to need it here?

Comment: Then again, I'm not sure what `\RepeatCell` is actually doing, so I should probably shut up.